# Infinite dimensional space as a length of a vector or as a number of basis function.

Tags: vector-spaces, function-spaces

I have been confused by the term infinite dimensional.

The first time I saw it was in the context of vector space. The way I understand it is that a function can be seen as collection of infinitely many points and thus can be seen as an infinitely long vector. Infinite here can be seen as the length of a vector, I think.
https://solitaryroad.com/c850.html

However, I also know that there exist infinite dimensional vector spaces which are characterized by the property that the spaces are spanned by infinitely many basis functions.
[https://www.math.purdue.edu/~shao92/documents/MA265_Review_Chapter_4.pdf](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eshao92/documents/MA265_Review_Chapter_4.pdf)

The first one is referring to the length of a vector or points a function can be evaluated, whereas the second one is referring to how many functions are required to represent a specific function. Therefore, I believe they are different concept although both have the term "infinite dimension".

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're both the second one (has an infinite basis).

The solitaryroad link is also using the term in the second sense.  I've never heard it used in anything like your first sense.

Comment: Thank you. In this material
https://cns.gatech.edu/~predrag/courses/PHYS-6124-12/StGoChap2.pdf
second page in the middle, it says that
“Consider F[a, b], the set of all real (or complex) valued functions f(x) on the interval [a, b]…We may think of the array of numbers (f(x)) for x ∈ [a, b] as being the components of the vector. Since there is an infinity of independent components — one for each point x — the space of functions is infinite dimensional.”.
Isn’t this using the second perspective I have posted, i. e., function as a vector with infinitely many elements?

Comment: @user1168149: Oh, I see what you mean.  That's just an analogy.  If you're used to vector spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each vector is represented as a list of scalars, then the number of scalars needed (the length of the list) equals the dimension of the space.  So the post is trying to explain infinite dimension by that analogy.  But it's not the definition, because abstractly, a vector does not have to be represented by anything resembling a list of scalars.  It can be any object in a space that supports addition and scalar multiplication, such as a space of functions.

Comment: @user1168149: When you said "length" I thought you meant in the geometric sense, like the norm of a vector.  It's true that a line in a vector space is "infinitely long", but that has nothing to do with dimension.

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing explanation. I think I understand, now. Ironically, the analogy with infinitely many elements confused me, making me think that there exist two different definitions of “infinite dimensional” space. However, the formal one is the with infinite sum of basis functions and the other one with infinite elemental vector is just for explanation and thus not a formal definition.

Comment: Is my understanding above correct?